# Adobe Reader DC and SumatraPDF can not read the hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, pdf

I'm trying to insert a link to a website into my document by package `hyperref`. I could not understand why the errors appear when I read the output PDF in Adobe Reader DC and SumatraPDF.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left = 1in, right = 1in, top = 0.7in, bottom = 0.7in]{dsfont,bbm,geometry,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern,amssymb,parskip}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\begin{document}

\parindent 0.4in

Links to my professional mathematicians \href{https://www.tse-fr.eu/people/jerome-renault}{Jérôme Renault} and \href{https://www.tse-fr.eu/people/stephane-villeneuve}{Stéphane Villeneuve} has changed the course my life.

\end{document}
```

Here are the error messages:

1. From Adobe Reader DC

[image]

2. From SumatraPDF

[image]

Please help me solve this problem! I'm writing this as a motivation letter. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You might want to specify which latex installation you're using, and isøts version. Plus version of the hyperref package. If you add `\listfiles` before the document class all package versions are written to the log file.

Comment: You should get lots of errors from `\usepackage[left = 1in, right = 1in, top = 0.7in, bottom = 0.7in]{dsfont,bbm,geometry,amsmath}
`, but the links works fine. Show your log-file.

Comment: I have no such problem with the result of this code in either pdf viewers, once I have loaded `geometry` with its options separately.

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer, I use Bakoma for editor. How can I find where the log-file is saved?

Comment: Hi @Bernard, you meant `\usepackage[left = 1in, right = 1in, top = 0.7in, bottom = 0.7in]{geometry}`? I have just separated `geometry' but to no avail.

Comment: When I render this tex document on overleaf, everything is fine. Maybe the problem lies in my Bakoma.

Comment: I have no idea. I never used Bakoma - ask their support what's going on.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Just in case: are your packages up-to-date?

Comment: @Bernard, I added `\listfiles` right before `\begin{document}` to generate the log-file, but I only found the PDF.

Comment: You can read the details in the .log file.